# Are there any drinking water fountains/taps in Paris Charles de Gaulle airport?

Tags: airports, paris, cdg, airport-terminals, tap-water

I'm not a big fan of spending 3`EUR` for a 250ml bottle of water, hence the question: **are there any drinking water fountains/taps in Paris Charles de Gaulle airport, be it airside or at departures/arrivals level?** Ideally I would like to either drink directly from the tap/fountain or refill an empty water bottle.

Using the taps in the washrooms at CDG might not be an option, since these dispense tempered (warmish) water suitable for hand/face washing. Moreover they are sensor-activated and provide a relatively slow water flow which could make refilling a bottle a tedious process. Below is a picture of a washroom at CDG, courtesy of Karen Bryan on Flickr:

[image]

<sup>*Toilets at Paris CDG Airport, Karen Bryan, Fair use*</sup>

Comment: Plenty. They're called "taps".

Comment: Do you want to fill up an empty bottle? or want to see an actual drinking fountain?  I like the comment by @O.R.Mapper because taps at CDG are cleared for drinking anyway.

Comment: @gayotfow Both. The point is getting access to drinking water without having to pay through your nose. If you have references to back up the potability of the water from toilet taps at cdg by all means add an answer.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Drinking or filling a water bottle from a restroom tap is often impractical, and sometimes unsafe.  (Even in places where tap water is generally safe to drink, the same does not always apply to *hot* tap water, which is often all you can get from a bathroom tap.)

Comment: @NateEldredge: I have never heard any concerns about hot tap water being unsafe in Western Europe (nor experienced any issues after drinking some). With that said, I have yet to see a tap over here where you can *only* get hot water. If anything, it's an old building and on some taps, you can get only *cold* water.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: See for example http://www.nytimes.com/2008/01/29/health/29real.html (and we can take it to Skeptics.SE if necessary).  Perhaps "unhealthy" is a better term than "unsafe." Not sure about Europe, but public buildings in the US increasingly have bathroom taps that have no handles, only an optical sensor, and when triggered it dispenses warm water; there is no way to get just cold water.  (The sensor also makes it hard to drink or fill bottles, and the flow rate is often low enough that it would take a long time to get very much water.)

Comment: @NateEldredge: Ok, not sure how common lead plumbing is over here. In any case, those optical sensor-controlled taps are quite rare here, and come to think of it, when I have encountered them, they, to, released only *cold* (or at least cool) water.

Comment: @JoErNanO, there's a question in here somewhere that cites the drinking water regulations for France.  I remember verifying the answer's links, but can't find it now

Comment: @NateEldredge You have a point. Indeed [sinks in CDG toilets have a single automatic sensor-activated taps](https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8467/8116841255_9f3a98812e_b.jpg) which dispense tempered (warmish) water only.

Comment: It's possibly worth noting that the answer to this question will vary between terminals. Terminals 1, 2 and 3 are all very different buildings.

Comment: Note that lead piping has been [banned in construction in France since 1995](http://www.afnor.org/fiches/faq-reglementation/canalisations-en-plomb), so at least the newer terminals shouldn't have an issue with that.

Comment: In CDG, some terminals have fountains, but not all. I don't remember offhand which ones do.

Comment: Just refilled at 2E near gate 47 :)

Comment: There is one in 2F, gate F56, next to the massage/pedicure shop.

Comment: There is one next to toilettes near gate m25 terminal 2E.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Yes, but not everywhere.

Below is an image of what  the water fountains look like at the airport at the time of writing (07/2015):

[image: CDG water fountain] 
<sup>*CDG water fountain*, JoErNanO, Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0</sup>

Apparently, the fountains are used in other airports - but I found another mention of it in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YnkO-9ECSE), which also attributes it to CDG. It is a side view, but it matches up.

I also found [this](http://andysgapyear.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/on-beginnings-and-parisian-water-fountains/) blog post, which says

> The fountain (I’ll try to post pictures) was a tall, orange thing with two buttons on each side, like a pinball machine, and instead of a spout, a metal disc with no clear hole. I saw some savvy French woman get a sip, but when I tried I had no luck. I pushed the left button. A blue light turned on, but no water. I pushed the right button. No change. I put my phone down and pushed both buttons. A different blue light went on. I was totally confused, and still thirsty.

### Where Are the Fountains

Recent, hands-on experience with the airport show that drinking water can be found in the following locations:

#### Terminal 2

- Terminal 2D: there is a fountain in the Schengen zone (after security) next to the toilets between gate D54 and D55
- Terminal 2D: there is a fountain in the check-in area (before security) next to the male toilets between desks 9 and 8
- Terminal 2E: there is a fountain between gates L25 and L26 (as of 19 Jan 2019), between M25 and M26 (near Toilets) and between M46 and M47. Also in front of K37 (3 Nov 2022) (EDIT: As of 9 April 2023, the fountain in front of K37 is still there, and there is now a fountain in front of K45 as well. It’s in front of the toilets.)
- Terminal 2F: there is a fountain after security in front of gates F29/F30 <strike>out of order as of 22/07/16.</strike> Working again as of April 2017. Working water fountain next to F21 as well.
- Terminal 2F, arrivals floor: inside the entrance to the toilets, near Marks & Spenser Food. There is confirmed water fountain next to La Maison Du Chocolat across F24 (June 2019)
- Terminal 2G: near the toilets

(Please edit if you have information about other areas)

Comment: Can confirm 2E between L25 and L26 as of 2019. I found no other taps around the L gates.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I found another water fountain at terminal 3 (for budget airlines) between gates 7 and 8.

(Edit)

I found another water fountain today, also at terminal 3, Hall A, but between gate 3 & 4.  I think this is a different part of the terminal to the one at gate 7 above, which I think is only accessible via Hall B, so it’s worth mentioning here.

Answer (score 3):

And an additional update, as of January 2018, there is this water drinking fountain in CDG Terminal 2E, located near gate K34:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Found this one near gate T2A-A47. Climb up the stairs and on the way to the restrooms you will find one past the closed smoking cubes

Comment: Confirming this fountain is still here, as of August 2022. Being from the US, which has an abundance of fountains in airports, I feel a little silly consulting StackExchange for fountains, but here we are.